# PHP 100% CPU usage with Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, sublimetext3, cpu-usage

I use Sublime Text 3 for web development. From time to time, it starts PHP process with CPU usage of 100%. My Mac starts to be laggy then and fans are loud.

How can I investigate why is it happening? I think it's one of the plugins that I'm using: `SublimeLinter-php` or `SublimeLinter-phpcs`, but I'm not sure.

Is there any way to check it out other than just disabling plugins and waiting if that happens? That would be troublesome, because sometimes it happens after a few hours and development without them is troublesome for me. Have you experience this kind of behavior with Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Did you checked the Activity monitor?

Comment: Yes, that's how I know that it's PHP process that is taking this CPU energy. I couldn't find any more helpful information though.

Comment: Try to set your `caret_style` setting to either blink, wide, or solid And see if it fixes the problem. Or install a fresh version of it without plugins.

Comment: Keep in mind Sublime Text 3 is still in beta and the problem you are encountering might be related to some kind of bug not yet discovered. The best thing would be to ask the software provider for the support directly.

Answer (score 30):

It might be caused by Sublime's file indexing. (https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/537)

Try adding `"index_files": false` to your user preferences (`Preferences > Settings - User`) and see if that helps.

If it does, you might be able to troubleshoot it using this page: http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/file-indexing

Comment: I'm sure it's not file indexing. It happens when you write certain syntax, like empty `foreach`. It has something to do with PHP parsing.

Comment: @Tom I met this problem on win10,ST use 100% cpu when I Open this editor, disable index files works well here. When I save user settings ,CPU usage got down immediatly.

Comment: I'm using Sublimetext 3 in linux (kubuntu) and your solution worked for me :)

Comment: What does it need to index?

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue too with web/nodejs projects.
Instead of completely disabling the indexing, i just ignored my node_modules folder which contains node dependencies.

I you are working with php, you may ignore some folders such as vendor.

In your settings add the following line :

Example :

```
"index_exclude_patterns": ["*.log", "node_modules/*", "vendor/*"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that Sublime Text 3 on Yosemite (Macbook Air 2014) had begun to lag, looking at the Activity Monitor Sublime was at 150% CPU.  After finding this thread that we're currently reading, about how a plugin for SublimeLinter was the source of some problems, I disabled SublimeLinter-jshint and Sublime immediately dropped.  Unfortunate, because it is an awesome tool for Sublime.

It is now idling between 2% and 10% after disabling jsHint.

Comment: Read here?? where is the link?

Comment: This thread, reading literally this page. Here. Edited to prevent confusion.

Comment: How can something be 150% ? :P

Comment: :D good question, I'm sure someone out there can explain it but that's what Activity Monitor reported.

Comment: you can also try setting the `lint_mode` to `load/save`. That fixed SublimeLinter-jshint maxing out the CPU for me.

Comment: Whoa! That is quite the solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

PhpConnector gives me also high cpu usage. I removed it ant all went back to normal. So, in my case both PhpConnector and SublimeLinter-phpcs provoke high cpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue with SublimeLinter-phpcs installed. I can verify that phpcs is the cause of the issue. It's not the SublimeLinter plugin itself, but the PHP_CodeSniffer process that is hanging and causing 100% CPU usage.

The only solution at the moment, until PHP_CodeSniffer fixes the bug, is to remove the SublimeLinter-phpcs plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here - the root couse was A File Icon plugin

After removing usage went from 200% to 3%